# how to split a mixed data column to separate int and str columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a column which has data like mileage and data as 24.5 km 11.3 km .I want to separate integer value and string value and make 2 diff columns. how to do it.?

I have mileage

```
    11.5km
    21.4km
```

I want integer

```
      11.5   
      21.4

STRING
 km
 km
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df[["integer", "string"]] = df["mileage"].str.extract(pat=r"(\d+\.?\d*)(.*)")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  mileage integer string
0  11.5km    11.5     km
1  21.4km    21.4     km
```